# Datawarehouse in Hive

Tags: hive, data-warehouse

I have a requirement to make datawarehouse in Hive and use HBase to serve real time access 
So I would like to know what would be the architecture for the same
Can I first dump the data on HBase and access it as Rest Service and create external table in Hive and run hive queries on it ?
Will Hive be distributed i.e i need to install Hive on all nodes of my cluster or it it will be central

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your questions:

Hive will be distributed.

For best performance, I would consider installing Hive on every node of the cluster. Hive translates HiveQL into MapReduce jobs - the jobs will be performed where the data is. If that's not possible, the data will have to move to the job. For the sake of response time, you'll want Hive on every node.

To create a Hive table that references data stored in HBase, you can check out the [Hive - HBase Integration wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration). Here's a quick example:

```
CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");
```

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah for your inputs

Comment: So I can use HBase for my near real time queries ? and for data transformation hive queries will run on HBase Tables

Comment: You got it! As long as you structure your data in a way that makes it easy to read with HBase you should be able to use HBase for real time access and Hive for bulk processing and transformation. Keep in mind that Hive is `INSERT`/`DELETE` only - there's no update.

Comment: How to create Data Marts in Hive ? Will it be created on the same node of hive or i need to to move the data marts to some other node